# Получить url при помощи регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день) Есть ссылка https://www.labnol.org/internet/duplicate-gmail-draft-emails/29124/, из неё с помощью регулярного выражения необходимо получить
url страницы в виде duplicate-gmail-draft-emails-29124. Помогите пожалуйста, раньше с регулярками не сталкивалась

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/MdBOrV/1

Comment: если я правильно поняла, мне необходимо написать вот такое выражение                                ^.+?\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/$

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю какое регулярное выражение мне писать?

Comment: `^.+?\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/$` заменить на `$1-$2`

Comment: ^.+?\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/$1-$2  так?

Comment: Вы в чем это пишете? В смысле среды/языка

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/MdBOrV/2

```
/(?:([^\/]+)\/){3}([^\/]+)/
```

В матчах (совпадениях) $1 и $2 - будет то, что нужно.
Нужно объединить через конкатенацию:
`$1+'-'+$2` или `$match[1]."-".$match[2]`